What is the proper way to deploy a c# wpf app with a dependency to Python code?
I am building a C# Wpf application that uses a Pythonnet function to compute sky coordinates from pixel position in a fits file. (It communicates with Python installation by using PythonNet library).
However, I do not know how to distribute the app through the Microsoft Store, when finished, because I must bundle Python and Astropy Python libraries with the main app.
This is the code mentioned above
public static double[] GetCoordinatesForPixelsOfImage(int pixelX, int pixelY, string imageUrl)
{
    if (Runtime.PythonDLL == null)
    {
        Runtime.PythonDLL = "Python312.dll";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
    }

    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        dynamic module1 = Py.Import("astropy.io.fits");
        dynamic module2 = Py.Import("astropy.wcs");

        dynamic image = module1.open(imageUrl);
        dynamic wcs = module2.WCS(image[0].header);
        dynamic arrayOfCoords = np.array(wcs.pixel_to_world_values(pixelX, pixelY));

        image.close();

        return arrayOfCoords;            
    }
}

How can I bundle Python with my app ?
Is it common practice to deploy python with a c# app and what alternatives exist ?
